# PHP Server settings causing problem

Tags: php, apache

On my site http://www.mediadeals.co.uk , I'm getting this strange error. The site was working perfectly well a week ago on the old server.

The error is:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class
>   soapclient in
>   /home125b/sub013/sc71724-JPYM/www.mediadeals.co.uk/www/includes/libs/payment/do_payment.php
>   on line 5261

I'm sure it is to do with server settings. Does anyone know what I need to do?

Coding is absolutely fine, for sure.

Comment: The coding is absolutely not fine, if errors like that get printed for all the world to see. You need to change your error reporting settings. That won't fix the problem you're having though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm guessing you have recently updated to a new version of PHP. You probably need to remove an include to something like nusoap.php as it clashes with the soap class within PHP5 and its likely not required anymore.

Answer (score 5):

[`SoapClient`](http://php.net/SoapClient) is now a built-in class in PHP.
If you have any scripts using that class name you'll have to change them.

Comment: How do I do that Greg? Any ideas?

Comment: You could do a find & replace on your files to change SoapClient to MySoapClient, for example

Comment: 'fraid I'm too busy at the moment (braces for "why are you on SO" comments)